# SwiftUI List Expand/Collapse All Programmatically

Tags: list, recursion, swiftui, hierarchy

How can one **expand / collapse all** nodes in the following sample SwiftUI Hierarchical List?

Not sure if its possible with List/Outlinegroup or whether one needs to implement a custom recursive view with Disclosuregroup

Reference: https://www.appcoda.com/learnswiftui/swiftui-expandable-list.html

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tree: [MenuItem]
    init() {
        tree = sampleMenuItems
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(tree, id: \.id, children: \.subMenuItems)
        { node in

            Text(node.name)
        }
    
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String

    var subMenuItems: [MenuItem]?
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
var espressoMachines = MenuItem(name: "Espresso Machines", subMenuItems: espressoMachineMenuItems)
var grinders = MenuItem(name: "Grinders", subMenuItems: grinderMenuItems)
var otherEquipment = MenuItem(name: "Other Equipment", subMenuItems: otherMenuItems)

let sampleMenuItems = [ espressoMachines, grinders, otherEquipment]
                        

// Sub-menu items for Espressco Machines
let espressoMachineMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Leva", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Leva X"), MenuItem(name: "Leva S") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Strada", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Strada EP" ), MenuItem(name: "Strada AV"), MenuItem(name: "Strada MP"), MenuItem(name: "Strada EE") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "KB90"),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Linea", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "Linea PB X"), MenuItem(name: "Linea PB"), MenuItem(name: "Linea Classic") ]),
                                 MenuItem(name: "GB5"),
                                 MenuItem(name: "Home", subMenuItems: [ MenuItem(name: "GS3"), MenuItem(name: "Linea Mini") ])
                                ]

// Sub-menu items for Grinder
let grinderMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Swift"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Vulcano"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Swift Mini"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Lux D")
                        ]

// Sub-menu items for other equipment
let otherMenuItems = [ MenuItem(name: "Espresso AV"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Espresso EP"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Pour Over"),
                         MenuItem(name: "Steam")
                        ]
```

Comment: You need to use DisclosureGroup directly to have access to that feature. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64245991/12299030.

Comment: Good example however that would only work with a child depth of 1 - really looking for a recursive view example with disclosure group for an unlimited child depth. But that becomes problematic to keep the child and parents observable for dynamic data

Comment: Check even [https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/02/displaying-recursive-data-using-outlinegroup-in-swiftui](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/02/displaying-recursive-data-using-outlinegroup-in-swiftui/)

Comment: Thanks but looking for a **recursive** Disclosuregroup

Comment: This is the best example of a recursive Disclosuregroup (https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-hierarchy-list/). The only issue is the child subview is not observable and thus doesn't update when children change