# Is it possible to make SwiftUI List item text selectively bold for FAQ section?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI expandable FAQ view with Question text that I want **bold** and Answer text that I want to leave as non-bold text.

I am only able to make either BOTH bold OR both regular weight but want to know if it is possible to selective make the question text bold only??

Below is my code and screen-shot of what I have so far.

[image]

**FAQ VIEW**

```
struct FAQ: View {
   
    let questionItems : [QuestionAnswer] = [ qa1(), qa2(), qa3() ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(questionItems, children: \.textTwo) { item in
                Text(item.textOne)
                     //.bold() makes BOTH bold or regular without
                     .padding([.top, .bottom], 15)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .clipped()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Frequently asked questions", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

func qa1() -> QuestionAnswer {
    return .init(textOne: "Question one", textTwo: [.init(textOne: "Answer one")])
}

func qa2() -> QuestionAnswer {
    return .init(textOne: "Question two", textTwo: [.init(textOne: "Answer two")])
}

func qa3() -> QuestionAnswer {
    return .init(textOne: "Question three", textTwo: [.init(textOne: "Answer three")])
}
```

**DATA MODEL**

```
struct QuestionAnswer: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let textOne: String
    var textTwo: [QuestionAnswer]?
}
```

Comment: What about trying an attributed string,`Text("**\(item.textOne)**")`

Comment: It makes everything bold too, good idea though...

Comment: You can use `DisclosureGroup` and style group label explicitly as you wish. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64245991/12299030.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if a row has any children to decide whether to bold the text or not.

```swift
List(questionItems, children: \.textTwo) { item in
    if item.hasChildren {
        Text(item.textOne)
            .bold()
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 15)
    } else {
        Text(item.textOne)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 15)
    }
}

extension QuestionAnswer {
    var hasChildren: Bool { !(textTwo?.isEmpty == true) }
}
```

Or with suggested approach from the comments

```swift
List(questionItems, children: \.textTwo) { item in
    Text(item.hasChildren ? "**\(item.textOne)**" : item.textOne )
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 15)
}
```

Comment: This works but the extension var hasChildren needs to be FALSE, not TRUE.

Comment: Oh, my bad. the previous version needed to be negated since we also need to cover the case with `nil`

Answer (score 1):

The other approach you can do is below one

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(questionItems) { item in
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        ForEach(item.textTwo ?? [QuestionAnswer]()) { innterItem in
                            Text(innterItem.textOne)
                        }
                    } label : {
                        Text(item.textOne)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .clipped()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Frequently asked questions", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this trick from the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list

```
struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var id: Self { self }
        var name: String
        var children: [FileItem]? = nil
        var description: String {
            switch children {
            case nil:
                return " \(name)"
            case .some(let children):
                return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
            }
        }
    }
```

Except instead of changing an icon in the description, you would add the ** suggested by @Joakim Danielson

Answer (score 0):

you may use attributed string .

```
extension Text {
    init(_ string: String, configure: ((inout AttributedString) -> Void)) {
        var attributedString = AttributedString(string) 
        configure(&attributedString) 
        self.init(attributedString) // Text initialization
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Your Text") { string in
            string.foregroundColor = .Color
            if let range = string.range(of: "Attributed") { 
                string[range].foregroundColor = .YourColor // Use Your Style
            }
        }
```

Use anywhere you need .
for your current problem use attributed string on your list . and you may design as you can .